# Apache Nutch 1.19 Getting Error: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

Tags: java, web-scraping, hadoop, solr, nutch

So, I set up Apache Nutch 1.19, Apache Solr 8.11.2, and Hadoop 3.3.5, to the best of my knowledge on a Windows 11 PC.

After, I went into the nutch directory and ran this command:
`bin/nutch generate crawl/crawldb crawl/segments`

Then, I got the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Below is the full output after running the command:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/wiki/a/ApacheNutch/apache-nutch-1.19/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.18.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/User/Desktop/wiki/a/ApacheNutch/apache-nutch-1.19/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2023-05-14 19:01:16,433 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginManifestParser [main] Plugins: looking in: C:\Users\User\Desktop\wiki\a\ApacheNutch\apache-nutch-1.19\plugins
2023-05-14 19:01:16,558 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main] Plugin Auto-activation mode: [true]
2023-05-14 19:01:16,558 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main] Registered Plugins:
2023-05-14 19:01:16,558 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Regex URL Filter (urlfilter-regex)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,558 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Html Parse Plug-in (parse-html)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,558 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    HTTP Framework (lib-http)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    the nutch core extension points (nutch-extensionpoints)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Basic Indexing Filter (index-basic)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Anchor Indexing Filter (index-anchor)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Tika Parser Plug-in (parse-tika)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Basic URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-basic)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Regex URL Filter Framework (lib-regex-filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Regex URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-regex)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    URL Validator (urlfilter-validator)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    CyberNeko HTML Parser (lib-nekohtml)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    OPIC Scoring Plug-in (scoring-opic)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Pass-through URL Normalizer (urlnormalizer-pass)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    Http Protocol Plug-in (protocol-http)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]    SolrIndexWriter (indexer-solr)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main] Registered Extension-Points:
2023-05-14 19:01:16,559 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Content Parser)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch URL Filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (HTML Parse Filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Scoring)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch URL Normalizer)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Publisher)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Exchange)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Protocol)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch URL Ignore Exemption Filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Index Writer)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Segment Merge Filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,560 INFO o.a.n.p.PluginRepository [main]     (Nutch Indexing Filter)
2023-05-14 19:01:16,969 INFO o.a.n.c.Generator [main] Generator: starting at 2023-05-14 19:01:16
2023-05-14 19:01:16,969 INFO o.a.n.c.Generator [main] Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
2023-05-14 19:01:16,969 INFO o.a.n.c.Generator [main] Generator: filtering: true
2023-05-14 19:01:16,969 INFO o.a.n.c.Generator [main] Generator: normalizing: true
2023-05-14 19:01:16,974 INFO o.a.n.c.Generator [main] Generator: running in local mode, generating exactly one partition.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1454)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.<init>(FileSystem.java:2180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:2179)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listLocatedStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:783)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:279)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:327)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1571)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1568)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:525)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1589)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.generate(Generator.java:895)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.run(Generator.java:1119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:81)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Generator.main(Generator.java:1066)
```

Comment: Requirements for Nutch: 1. Unix environment, or Windows-Cygwin environment
2. Java Runtime/Development Environment (JDK 11 / Java 11). ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/NutchTutorial. Check your java version.

Comment: The Hadoop native libraries are only built for unix machines... Did you build/download them on your own?

Comment: Ended up giving up on the windows installation of Nutch etc and did it in WSL, the Linux for Windows thing.

Comment: Do you have any link to documentation that explains how to submit nutch crawl job to hadoop? The one on wiki is or older version of nutch.

Comment: @DarshanParab Bro the only way I was able to make any sense of things was to use ChatGPT4.  The paid version.  But, ultimately, I ended up just going with python scrapy and building a distributed crawling system that uses Redis.